# Problems with mousepressevent

Tags: python, pyqt, mouseevent, signals, mousepress

I just asked a similar question but (sorry!) I think I'll need more help. I have a problem with signals in pyqt. Let me post the whole code, it isn't long and it is easier for me to explain...

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt
import time
import math

class FenixGui(QtGui.QWidget):

    def backgroundmousepressevent(self, event):
        print "test 1"
        self.offset = event.pos()


    def backgroundmousemoveevent(self, event):
        print "test 2"
        x=event.globalX()
        y=event.globalY()
        x_w = self.offset.x()
        y_w = self.offset.y()
        self.move(x-x_w, y-y_w)


    def __init__(self):
        super(FenixGui, self).__init__()

        # setting layout type
        hboxlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(hboxlayout)

        # hiding title bar
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # setting window size and position
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 862, 560)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(False)

        # creating background window label
        backgroundpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("fenixbackground.png")
        self.background = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.background.setPixmap(backgroundpixmap)
        self.background.setGeometry(0, 0, 862, 560)

        # making window draggable by the window label
        self.connect(self.background,QtCore.SIGNAL("mousePressEvent()"),         self.backgroundmousepressevent)
        self.connect(self.background,QtCore.SIGNAL("mouseMoveEvent()"), self.backgroundmousemoveevent)


        # fenix logo
        logopixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("fenixlogo.png")
        self.logo = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.logo.setPixmap(logopixmap)
        self.logo.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 150)


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    exm = FenixGui()
    exm.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

All right, so this is the code, it's just a simple gui that I wanted to make draggable around the screen clicking and dragging on any place in the background. My problem is: backgroundmousepressevent and backgroundmousemoveevent DON'T get fired when i press or move the button. So I wonder: where's the error? Did I mispell something or what? Thank you very much!

Matteo

Comment: Please, please adapt to an existing coding style. I'd suggest the "Python coding style": http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ 
But since you seem to work with PyQt a lot, maybe the Qt coding style is better suited for you: http://developer.qt.nokia.com/wiki/Qt_Coding_Style

Comment: It seems pretty obvious he was mainly just having problems with copy/paste, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Qt, events are different from signals and slots.  Events are represented by `QEvent` objects that are passed to the `event()` method of `QObject`s, where they are typically dispatched to specialized methods such as `mousePressEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent`.  Since they are not signals, you cannot connect them to slots.

Instead, just re-implement event functions to do custom things.  Make sure to call the original implementation with `super`, though, unless you know what you are doing.

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    super(FenixGui, self).mousePressEvent(event)
    print "test 1"
    self.offset = event.pos()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    super(FenixGui, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
    print "test 2"
    x=event.globalX()
    y=event.globalY()
    x_w = self.offset.x()
    y_w = self.offset.y()
    self.move(x-x_w, y-y_w)
```

Typically, Qt will warn you when trying to connect to non-existing signals, by writing a warning message to the console.  Additionally, you can prevent this situation by using [new-style signals and slots](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/new_style_signals_slots.html) instead of the old-style, more C++-ish `SIGNAL()` function:

```
lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
lineEdit.valueChanged.connect(self.myHandlerMethod)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to connect to QWidget's mousePressEvent and mouseMoveEvent signals, but they don't exist as signals. Try overriding the methods instead. This works for me:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt
import time
import math

class FenixGui(QtGui.QWidget):

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "test 1"
        self.offset = event.pos()
        QtGui.QWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        print "test 2"
        x=event.globalX()
        y=event.globalY()
        x_w = self.offset.x()
        y_w = self.offset.y()
        self.move(x-x_w, y-y_w)
        QtGui.QWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)

    def __init__(self):
        super(FenixGui, self).__init__()

        # setting layout type
        hboxlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(hboxlayout)

        # hiding title bar
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        # setting window size and position
        self.setGeometry(200, 200, 862, 560)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(False)

        # creating background window label
        backgroundpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("fenixbackground.png")
        self.background = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.background.setPixmap(backgroundpixmap)
        self.background.setGeometry(0, 0, 862, 560)

        # fenix logo
        logopixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("fenixlogo.png")
        self.logo = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        self.logo.setPixmap(logopixmap)
        self.logo.setGeometry(100, 100, 400, 150)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    exm = FenixGui()
    exm.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```